# Calling a function - getting "lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand"

Tags: c

I'm currently blocked on a problem, and before you look at it, try to think that i'm a only a beginner trying to use a Pointer with a function.

I explain myself:
I need to have a menu ( Function ) who can lunch any other function, but my problem is that i was calling my function from my "main", so i tried to use pointer in my function.
I just learn how to use pointers so this is the first thing that comes to my ming right now.

Maybe its the wrong way, i'm still searching on the internet on how to do it or to do it right.

Right now i got this error message:

> lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand

Here is my corrected code: ( Simplified for maximum readability )

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void Menu(char *PointeurNameHuman, int *PointeurChoix, int *PointeurChoix1, int *PointeurChoix2, int *PointeurChoix3, void *PointeurWelcome())
{
    printf("\n\nEnter your choice: \n ");
    scanf("%d", PointeurChoix);

    while ((*PointeurChoix != 1) || (*PointeurChoix != 2) || (*PointeurChoix != 3))
    {
        if (*PointeurChoix == *PointeurChoix1)
        {
            printf("\n! Play! \n ");
            PointeurWelcome(PointeurNameHuman);
            return 0;
        }
        else if (*PointeurChoix == *PointeurChoix2)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else if (*PointeurChoix == *PointeurChoix3)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

void Welcome(char *PointeurNameHuman)
{
    printf("\n\nWelcome %s \nPlease enter your name: ", PointeurNameHuman);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char NameHuman[] = "HUMAN";
    int Choix, Choix1 = 1, Choix2 = 2, Choix3 = 3;

    char *PointeurNameHuman = &NameHuman;
    int *PointeurChoix = &Choix;
    int *PointeurChoix1 = &Choix1;
    int *PointeurChoix2 = &Choix2;
    int *PointeurChoix3 = &Choix3;

    void Welcome(PointeurNameHuman);

    void (*PointeurWelcome)() = &Welcome; // OLD Error

    Menu(PointeurNameHuman,PointeurChoix,PointeurChoix1,PointeurChoix2,PointeurChoix3,PointeurWelcome);
}
```

All comments about how to simplify my code is also welcomed !
Thanks in advance for all your answers and have a great day / night.

Edit: Thanks "b4hand" for this really quick answer, you pointed me in the right direction to solve my problem.

Comment: Do you have a line number for the error message? That would be helpful to point out in the question.

Comment: Attempting to form a `void*` by taking the address of a `void` expression

Comment: It looks like you want a function pointer. `void (*PointeurWelcome)() = &Welcome(PointeurNameHuman);`.

Comment: You don't do anything with `PointeurWelcome` after you've initialized it

Comment: You shouldn't edit your question to include the answer. The question no longer makes sense in the context of the answer.

Comment: The edit is still wrong

Comment: Enable warnings. `-Wall` on gcc and clang. Your code is not by any means correct even though it compiles.

Comment: The declaration for `Menu` is still wrong: `void Menu(char *PointeurNameHuman, int *PointeurChoix, int *PointeurChoix1, int *PointeurChoix2, int *PointeurChoix3, void (*PointeurWelcome)())`. The parenthesis around `PointeurWelcome` are required.

Comment: Question was low quality from the start and as now the solution is edited into the question it makes no sense at all, voting to close.

Comment: Sorry, first time that i use Stackoverflow ... Next time i'll do a better job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This declaration doesn't make sense:

```
void Welcome(char *PointeurNameHuman[50])
```

Do you perhaps mean the following?

```
void Welcome(char *PointeurNameHuman)
```

Also, this line is wrong:

```
void *PointeurWelcome = &Welcome(PointeurNameHuman);
```

You probably mean this as well:

```
void (*PointeurWelcome)() = &Welcome;
```

Likewise this line is strange:

```
char NameHuman[50] = "HUMAN";
```

Typically, you don't declare the array size when you initialize it with constant data. Instead, you could write this:

```
char NameHuman[] = "HUMAN";
```

The advantage to this is that you won't include all of the extra trailing zero bytes in your constant.

Also, the place inside `Menu` when you invoke `PointeurWelcome`, it is undeclared at that point in the code. That variable doesn't exist in that scope.

Also, inside `Menu`, typically people use local variables for reading data from `scanf`. For example, like this:

```
int Choix;
scanf("%d", &Choix);
```

Instead of what you have.

I strongly suggest you enable compiler warnings, as you will probably discover several other mistakes that you have made.

Comment: Thx to your reply i was enable to find and correct my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

N.B: Enable warnings on your compiler. `-Wall -pedantic` are good flags for GCC and clang. Consult your compiler's documentation for specifics.

`char *PointeurNameHuman[50]`, `char NameHuman[50]`, and `char *PointeurNameHuman` are different declarations. See this example in the standard:

§ 6.7.6.2

> 7 EXAMPLE 1
>
> ```
> float fa[11], *afp[17];
> ```
>
> declares an array of float numbers and an array of pointers to float
>   numbers.

Refer to [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/) if you ever have trouble with declarations.

`char *PointeurNameHuman = &NameHuman;` does not do what you think.

```
main.cpp:4:31: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
     char *PointeurNameHuman = &NameHuman;
```

You probably meant to do `char *PointeurNameHuman = NameHuman;` instead, although this is unnecessary because [arrays decay to pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying).

```
void Welcome(char* PointeurNameHuman)
{
    printf("\n\nWelcome %s \nPlease enter your name: ", PointeurNameHuman);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char NameHuman[] = "HUMAN";
    Welcome(NameHuman);
    return 0;
}
```

Secondly, to address your original error, you have the incorrect syntax for a function pointer. `void *` declares a void pointer, not a function pointer. In your edit, you changed it to `void (*PointerWelcome)() = &Welcome(variable)` which is still incorrect. You're now trying to take the address of a void expression. Use `void (*)()` instead:

```
void (*PointerWelcome)() = &Welcome;
PointerWelcome(variable);
```

---

For some reason, you declare a local function prototype in your main function. You already have a definition for `Welcome`, remove:

```
void Welcome(PointeurNameHuman);
```

If `PointeurNameHuman` had a type, it would conflict with your previous declaration of `Welcome`.

You declare your `Menu` function void, yet you return 0 in three different places. Either change `Menu`'s signature to `int Menu(...)` or change your return expressions to `return;`.

And finally, you're still not declaring a function pointer correctly.

```
void Menu( /* ... */ void (*PointeurWelcome)())
```

Comment: Founded the mistake before you answered but its the right answer for the problem and you helped me to optimized my code.